# How do I use indexpathforselectedrow to get an instance from my array of structs?

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, segue

I'm building an app for school. The app is sort of a dictionary app that includes a table of vocabulary words (my WordsTableViewController) embedded into a navigation controller, and my Definition View Controller which shows the vocab word and its corresponding definition.

The problem is that I have no idea how to use indexpathforselectedrow to get the appropriate vocabulary word from my vocabController's vocabWords array. The 'Vocabulary Words' are struct instances located in its own separate swift file.

All of it will be in my prepare for segue inside of my WordsTableViewController swift file.

Any help is really appreciated.

The table views number of rows looks like this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return myListVocab.vocabWords.count
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "ShowDefinitionSegue" {
        if let definitionVC = segue.destination as? DefinitionViewController {
            let index = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
            let indexPathForSelectedRow = index.row
            definitionVC.vocabWord[index]
            let vocab = myListVocab.vocabWords[indexPathForSelectedRow]
        }
    }
}
```

The error I'm getting is that I have an ambiguous reference to member `tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)`

The rest of my errors in my program so far is 'override can be specified only on class members'

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing it in `prepare(for:sender:)` push the `DefinitionViewController` manually in `UITableViewDelegate's` `tableView(_: didSelectRowAt:)` method, i.e

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let definitionVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DefinitionViewController") as? DefinitionViewController {
        let word = myListVocab.vocabWords[indexPath.row] //get the word using indexPath...
        definitionVC.word = word //set the word in definitionVC's property...
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(definitionVC, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Don't forget to set the `Storyboard ID` of `DefinitionViewController` as `DefinitionVC` in the `storyboard`.

Also, remove the `segue` that you created in the `storyboard`. Otherwise, the `DefinitionViewController` will be pushed twice unnecessarily.

Answer (score 0):

First implement [didSelectRow](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614989-deselectrow) in your `WordsTableViewController`. Then create instance variable `selectedWord`. After that, you can get the the selected word in `didSelectRow` by calling:

`selectedWord = myListVocab.vocabWords[indexPath.row]`

After assignment, you can use `selectedWord` in `prepareForSegue`

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
     if segue.identifier == "ShowDefinitionSegue" {
          if let definitionVC = segue.destination as? DefinitionViewController {
                 destinationVC.word = selectedWord
          }
      }
}
```

Comment: thanks. after trying this code, my view controllers on my storyboard went black and my simulator disappeared. I'm getting an error 'a build only device cannot be used to run this target' how do i change it back? i'm not sure if i understand what happened because your answer made sense to me.

Comment: Storyboard issue can not be related to the code that I posted. It seems XCode got broken, try restarting it.

Comment: My app still doesn't build. Ok I'm getting these errors. https://imgur.com/ltC0Zc1 https://imgur.com/39SHuWd .. hopefully it can be seen clearly in my screenshot.